# docker assigned an ip I can not find ipconfig but it exists

Tags: docker, nginx, ip

On Windows 7 I installed docker which brings up a headless VM. For the first test I built the largest `nginx` and ran `8080:80`, but then I could not browse it on my Windows.

Attempts by `localhost:8080` failed.

Then I performed:

```
docker inspect [MY-CONTEINER-ID]
```

I tried to use the `ip` I found there as `172`, obviously another fail

Further I used `ipconfig` on Windows and I found `192.168.99.1`, but it also failed. Eventually after hours, I accidentally browsed `192.168.99.100:8080` and it worked!

Could you please let me know that how I could find where this `192.168.99.100` is assigned, what the logic is and by which command I could reveal it?

Comment: IF you run `docker-machine ls` this should show all Docker Machine VMs that are running and their associated IPs. Or simply, `docker-machine ip default` where default is your machine name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the comments by Matt Clark it solved!

I commanded

```
docker-machine ls
```

and I got the ip I was confused about. Thank you.